# common bash function to check arguments and if "--help" was passed, then call a help function

Tags: bash

I have the following condition in a few bash functions to print their help message, but I realized that this is such an annoying repetition and wonder if there's a way around it so that the condition and call happen in a single wrapper function. So instead of this:

```sh
fn1() {
  arg=$@
  [ ! -z $arg ] || [ $arg = "--help" ] && helpit "fn1 help msg." && return

  # fn body here
}
fn2() {
  arg=$@
  [ ! -z $arg ] || [ $arg = "--help" ] && helpit "fn2 help msg." && return

  # fn body here
}
```

We have this:

```sh
try_help() {
  # FYI $@ is the help msg and not the params of its caller
  arg=$@
  [ ! -z $arg ] || [ $arg = "--help" ] && helpit "Delete a remote branch by name." && return 1
  return 0
}
fn1() {
  try_help "fn1 help msg." || return

  # fn body here
}
fn2() {
  try_help "fn2 help msg." || return

  # fn body here
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Comment: `arg=$@` doesn't work the way you want, btw. It's _exactly_ identical to `arg=$*`, because `$@` can't be stored in a string variable at all (it can only be stored in arrays).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy so we can't forward them to the `try_help` for checking?

Comment: You can absolutely forward them, you just can't do it with a string variable. You could use a global/shared array, or you can just pass them on `try_help`'s argument list.

Comment: Also, `[ -z $arg ]` is buggy. **Always** quote: `[ -z "$arg" ]`

Comment: (storing your arguments _in an array_ looks like `args=( "$@" )`; see [BashFAQ #5](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) introducing arrays)

Comment: BTW, `... && helpit "something" && return 1` is a bad idea, because it executes `return 1` only if `helpit` has a successful exit status. Better to run `... && { helpit "something"; return 1; }` so the `return 1` runs even if `helpit` reports a failure.

Comment: ...to go more into why `[ -z $arg ]` is buggy: When you have an _unquoted_ empty argument list, it turns into no arguments at all, so you get `[ -z ]`, which is treated like `[ -n "-z" ]`, which is why it _appears_ to work. But it only "works" when `$arg` is a simple enough value; consider `arg='foo bar'`; you get `[ -z "foo" "bar" ]`, which is an invalid `test` command so the code throws an error instead of just silently returning false as it should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trivially done.

```
helpit() { echo "$*" >&2; }
try_help() {
  local help_msg arg
  help_msg=$1; shift
  if (( $# == 0 )); then
    echo "No arguments found. Printing help:" >&2
    helpit "$help_msg"
    return 1
  fi
  for arg in "$@"; do
    case $arg in
      --)     return 0;;
      --help) helpit "$help_msg"; return 1;;
    esac
  done
  return 0
}

fn1() {
  try_help "fn1 help msg" "$@" || return
  # fn body here
}
fn2() {
  try_help "fn2 help msg" "$@" || return
  # fn body here
}
```